# SQL Server - Group concat while joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am beginner to SQL Server.

I have success this to work:

```
select top 100 tpeople.firstname,tpeople.lastName,tpeople.city, STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(T2.education as varchar(50))
                    FROM   tpeopleEducation T2
                    where  tpeople.GUID = T2.PeopleGUID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1,1, '') as education

    from tpeople full join tpeopleEducation
    on tpeople.GUID = tpeopleEducation.PeopleGUID
    group by tpeople.GUID,tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City
```

Which outputs:

```
firstname|lastname|city|education
Joe       Doe      NYC  MIT,Harvard
John      Smith    LA   NYU
```

I am trying to get this to work. Here I needed to join like below, in order to get access to attributes (tAttributes) per person (tpeople) :

```
select top 100 tpeople.firstname,tpeople.lastName,tpeople.city

   ,STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(T2.attribute as varchar(50))
                    FROM    tattributes T2 
                   where  tpeoplecluendex.AttributeGUID = T2.GUID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1,1, '') as attributes       

   from tpeople 

   join tPeopleCluendex on tPeopleCluendex.CPSGUID = tpeople.GUID


   join tAttributes on tAttributes.guid = tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID

   group by tpeople.GUID,tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City,tAttributes.GUID,tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID
```

Output is:

```
firstname|lastname|city|attributes
Joe       Doe      NYC  test1
Joe       Doe      NYC  test2
John      Smith    LA   test1
```

Why it is not like:

```
firstname|lastname|city|attributes
Joe       Doe      NYC  test1,test2
John      Smith    LA   test1
```

Sorry, if I wrote some nonsense.

Any SQL Server Gurus that can point me the right way?

Please let me know if I should add more info. I will update my question.

Thanks,

Update 1:

```
select top 100 tpeople.GUID,tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City,tAttributes.GUID,tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID

   ,STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(T2.attribute as varchar(50))
                    FROM    tattributes T2 
                   where  tpeoplecluendex.AttributeGUID = T2.GUID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1,1, '') as attributes       

   from tpeople 

   join tPeopleCluendex on tPeopleCluendex.CPSGUID = tpeople.GUID


   join tAttributes on tAttributes.guid = tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID

   group by tpeople.GUID,tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City,tAttributes.GUID,tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID
```

Output is:

```
 GUID                                 FirstName                                          LastName                                           City                                               GUID                                 AttributeGUID                        attributes
    ------------------------------------ -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1E92D80A-1859-4A2A-AE69-00003FF7190B Joe                                               Doe                                                                                                2972FC47-8511-4429-BBA3-00E515E3769D 2972FC47-8511-4429-BBA3-00E515E3769D  test1
    1E92D80A-1859-4A2A-AE69-00003FF7190B Joe                                               Doe                                                                                                E317A420-1B25-4C6F-B8B3-164F185851E0 E317A420-1B25-4C6F-B8B3-164F185851E0  test2
```

Update 2:

This does it:

```
select  top 100 tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City,
       STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(tAttributes.attribute as varchar(50))
       FROM    tAttributes, tpeoplecluendex
       where tattributes.GUID = tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID  and tPeopleCluendex.CPSGUID = tpeople.GUID
       group by attribute FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '') as attributes       
from tpeople 
group by tpeople.GUID,FirstName,LastName,City
```

Comment: Likely because they have different GUIDs and you're grouping by GUIDs (among other things). It may be some other column that's causing the conflict in the grouping, but it's probably a grouping issue.

Comment: Remove tAttributes.GUID,tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID from group by

Answer (score 0):

Try to print all group by columns to see the difference -

```
select top 100 tpeople.GUID,tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City,tAttributes.GUID,tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID

   ,STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(T2.attribute as varchar(50))
                    FROM    tattributes T2 
                   where  tpeoplecluendex.AttributeGUID = T2.GUID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1,1, '') as attributes       

   from tpeople 

   join tPeopleCluendex on tPeopleCluendex.CPSGUID = tpeople.GUID


   join tAttributes on tAttributes.guid = tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID

   group by tpeople.GUID,tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City,tAttributes.GUID,tPeopleCluendex.AttributeGUID
```

Comment: I updated the question with the output to your query. How should I adjust it to see attribute in one row comma separated? THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

group the GUID while concatenating

```
select  tpeople.GUID,tpeople.FirstName,tpeople.LastName,tpeople.City,
       STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cast(tAttributes.attribute as varchar(50))
       FROM    tAttributes, tpeoplecluendex
       where AttributeGUID = GUID and tPeopleCluendex.CPSGUID = tpeople.GUID
       group by attribute FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1, '') as attributes       
from tpeople 
group by tpeople.GUID,FirstName,LastName,City
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work .... Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Ambiguous column name 'GUID'. Any ideas?

Comment: See Update 2. Figured it out